# Grails create link to webflow

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-webflow

Is it possible to use the Grails tag [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) to create a link to (the first state of) a Grails webflow?

### Update

I'm asking how to create a link to the first state of a flow from outside the flow, i.e. the page on which the link appears is **not** part of the flow.

Comment: Not sure if you're asking how to link to a webflow (i.e. initiate the webflow when the user is not currently in the flow) or if you're asking how to link to a specific state (i.e. the first state of the webflow) if you're already in the flow.  In the first case, you should be able to just specify the controller/action like always, if it's not working post code.  If it's the second case, I'm not 100% sure, but I think if you create the transition and include an `event` parameter in your map you can transition between states that way.

Comment: I've updated my question, thanks for pointing out the potential for confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="${createLink(controller:'controllerName', action:'flowNameActionMinusFlow')}">Start Flow</a>`